# Why can't we look at Birkat Kohanim if the Kohanim are covered by a tallit?

Tags: blessing, kohen-priest, birchas-kohanim

The Peninei Halacha writes ([here](https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/category/tefila/20-birkat-kohanim-the-priestly-blessing/#_te02ftn20_1)) that:

> He should not look at the Kohanim or at anything else, so as not to distract his thoughts from the berachah (Shulchan Aruch 128:23; Mishnah Berurah 89).
>
> The Chachamim established that a Kohen who has an abnormality on his body that would likely cause people to stare at him, and divert their thoughts from the berachah, may not ascend to bless the people. Therefore, before the Kohanim became accustomed to covering their faces and hands with their tallitot, any Kohen who had a deformity on his face or hands, such as unusual facial freckles or crooked fingers, would not ascend the duchan to bless the nation. However, today, when all Kohanim are accustomed to covering their faces with a tallit, a defect on one’s face or hands does not prevent a Kohen from reciting the blessing. Nevertheless, even today, if the Kohen has a noticeable deformity on his leg, he should not ascend the duchan to bless the people, for it might distract the minds of the listeners. However, if he is a permanent resident of the community, such that his defect no longer makes people curious, he may ascend to bless the nation, for it most likely will not distract the listeners (Shulchan Aruch 128:30 and 31).

Additionally, the Kohen's hand position during birkat Kohanim is supposed to symbolize the keruvim of the aron and Hashem's word emanating from between the keruvim. However, if the Kohanim cover themselves with a tallit, what is the problem of gazing at the Kohanim whilst they're performing birkat Kohanim whilst hidden under a tallit?

Comment: I didn't know this until I ate with a family of kohanim who were discussing it, but the kohanim turn around to face the kehilla during birkas kohanim, so they are actually visible!

Comment: @MosesSupposes my point was that they cover themselves with a tallit, so you dont actually see them and their hands.

Comment: I'm not sure that they are completely covered as they raise their hands.  Actually, now that I think about it, I have a faint memory of hearing something about that we don't look in case their tallis slips and they are revealed.

Comment: Indeed you are correct there is no problem. Some specifically look at the covered kohanim to maintain focus. Others avoid looking out of habit or in case a hand sticks out or whatever; after all there isn't anything to see since it's covered so why look? Do what helps you focus.

Comment: One of my rebbeim, a cohen, told me that he was duchening in front of my Rosh Yeshiva. Afterwards the Rosh Yeshiva told him, The minhag these days is to cover your hands. The rebbi said, You aren't supposed to look! He said, glancing is okay.

Comment: You're driving down a country road in the middle of the night, arrive at an intersection with clear visibility for miles. There isn't another vehicle in sight. Do you go through the red light?